# preg_match PHP suggestions

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm not too great at preg_match yet and I was wondering if someone could give me a hand.
I have an array of values e.g. `array("black*", "blue", "red", "grey*")` I need to find the values with a `*` at the end then return the word before it.

I believe preg_match() is the best way of doing it but I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Do you want the words without a trailing `*` to be returned too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *must* use a regex...

```
$words = array_map(function($word) {
   return preg_replace('/\*\z/', '', $word);
}, $arr);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gxfIzI).

...but you're probably better off not using regex and using something like...

```
$words = array_map(function($word) {
   return rtrim($word, '*');
}, $arr);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gnjRbe).

If you want to return *only* the words which have a trailing `*`, try something like this first...

```
$words = preg_grep('/\*\z/', $arr);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8UZyCu).

The only disadvantage with this (as mentioned in the comments) is PHP will iterate twice over the array. You can simply use a `foreach` loop to do both of these in one loop if you wish.

Also, it is worth mentioning anonymous functions are a PHP 5.3 thing. You can still most of this code, just separate the functions into their own named functions and pass a reference to them.

Comment: Won't that return the entire value, including the `*`?  The requirement seem to be to only capture the words, not the `*`.

Comment: @e.dan: I don't believe it will. Check the CodePads.

Comment: Minor point - array_map takes the array first, then the callback function.  It will work, though processing the array twice (once to search for an asterisk and then once to retrieve the word) seems a bit inefficient.

Comment: @majelbstoat: I think you'll find [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) accepts the callback first. As for the inefficiency, yes you could do it in one loop, but then you lose the pretty functional-ness :)

Comment: @alex Indeed you would.  And as for the order of arguments, I was confusing it with array_filter().  Ah, PHP, your lovely needle-haystack, haystack-needle argument ordering has confounded me again :)  - PS, worth noting that anonymous functions are only available for PHP 5.3+?

Comment: @alex: This is one of my (only) annoyances with SO - the ability to rewrite history so easily.  I made my comment when all you posted was the last solution, with `preg_grep()`, I think it does indeed return the words including the `*`, and my understanding of the question, which is admittedly a little unclear, was that he wanted to get back `'black','grey'` and not `'black*','grey*'`.

Comment: @e.dan: Ah yes, I considered that after I posted my comment. Someone once called them *ninja edits*, which I think is fitting.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys! I would like to know if a `*` has been found as well is possible.

Comment: @jonathandey That should have been made clear in the original question. You can use `strpos($str, '*') !== FALSE`.

Comment: @jonathandey If you're able to update your question, that will make things clearer :)  There are a couple of answers here that do what you need, using a variation on Alex's suggestion of strpos().

Answer (score 0):

If you always have an array like that (i.e. no complex strings, just word*), you really shouldn't use regular expressions, it's an overkill.
Use string functions, like strpos for searching and str_replace or rtrim for removing *.

> If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function instead of preg_replace().

— from [str_replace manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to use preg_match for this - simple char lookup on the string will work:

```
$words = array('red*', 'grey', 'white', 'green*');
$return = array();

foreach ($words as $word) {
    if ($word[strlen($word) - 1] === '*') {
        $return[] = substr($word, 0, -1);
    }
}
var_dump($return);
```

Comment: @alex Hello!  I am in fact a Brisbanite for two more days, after which time I will be a San Franciscan (though in reality, still a Pom!)

Comment: I see. Well, enjoy your journey!